# Convert data from a string into a datatable

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, datatable

i have a string that looks like this:

> MSG,4,111,11111,8963C4,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.036,2017/03/14,10:38:27.052,,,524,140,,,64,,,,,0
>   MSG,8,111,11111,4B199E,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.039,2017/03/14,10:38:27.053,,,,,,,,,,,,0
>   MSG,5,111,11111,4631CC,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.039,2017/03/14,10:38:27.053,,43000,,,,,,,0,,0,0
>   MSG,5,111,11111,502CC6,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.041,2017/03/14,10:38:27.053,,41000,,,,,,,0,,0,0
>   MSG,5,111,11111,3C66B0,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.042,2017/03/14,10:38:27.053,,36975,,,,,,,0,,0,0
>   MSG,8,111,11111,4B16BB,111111,2017/03/14,10:38:27.045,2017/03/14,10:38:27.102,,,,,,,,,,,,0

I want to put the data from this string into a table or an array with several lines and colums. I want to seperate the data with ',', and i know how to do that if i have a file, but in this case there is no file but a string.

I tried to seperate the string by lines first by doing this:

```
lines = data1.split("\n")
```

That worked but when i tried to seperate the list with a ',' like this:

```
lines.split(',')
```

it is giving me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Is there a command to sperate lists or create datatables or arrays out of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you use

```
lines = data1.split("\n")
```

lines is a list and the function split is for strings.

so if you want to apply it on a specific string you can take that using index and apply split() e.g

```
lines[0].split(',')
```

to create a table or list of lists you can loop on lines list and then apply split again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like,

```
import re 
a = 'MSG,4,111,11111\naa,bb'  #store your entire string here
print(re.split(' |,|\n', a)) # this will give you the list
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood this, you want to split every line at the occurence of `,`. If so, you can use

```
lines = data1.split('\n')  # list of strings
step2 = [line.split(',') for line in lines]  # split every string in that list,
                                             # this gives a list of lists of strings
```

This gives you a list of lists: the "sublist" `step2[n]` contains the strings you get when splitting `lines[n]` at every occurence of `,`. This contains some empty strings since your example has several consecutive commas.

If you want to flatten that list of lists to get just a list, you can use

```
step3 = [item for sublist in step2 for item in sublist]  # flatten that list
```

Answer (score 0):

After the help of @shahs i was able to get what i needed.

This is what the code looks like and it worked even though it probably isn't the best:

```
lines = data1.split("\n")
myarray = np.asarray(lines)
array = np.zeros(shape=(len(lines),22))
array=array.astype('str')

for i1 in range(len(lines)):
  for i2 in range(len(array[0])):
        data3=lines[i1].split(',')
        array[i1,i2]=data3[i2]
```